# jQuery - Change html of a submit button on submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, submit

What I want to do is pretty simple.
I've a form, with a submit button

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/some_url" id="some-form" method="post">
  ...
  <button class="btn" id="remove-selected" type="submit">Send</button>`
</form>
```

I want to change the html of the button with jQuery when the form is submitted but can't achieve that, seems like the form submission occurs before I can change it.

My code right now, dead simple:

```
$("#some-form").on("submit", function(e) {
  $("#remove-selected").html("Sending...");
});
```

Thanks for advises!

Comment: Actually it works in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari... Seems to be a Safari bug, shoulda try that before, my bad..

Answer (score 2):

Your stuff seems working for me, just submit the form via JS to have more control about the sequence and error cases.

```
$("#some-form").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#remove-selected").html("Sending...");
  $(this).submit();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GDAhe/1/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, when I do that, text is changing but form isn't submitted, can't figure out why..

Comment: In your example is no specific submit handling set. Do you have it in your form like <form method="get" action="./whatever">? If not you need to do this in JS via Ajax or whatever.

Comment: I just updated my post and fiddle, using click instead of submit handler. It seems working that way, the action url is called.

Comment: Thanks Sven but that way, the form is submitted when we click on any element, not only the button, that's not what I need. Anyway my problem seems to be a Safari problem, because the simpler solutions are working on other browsers.

Comment: You can change the way the form is submitted by changing the selector for the onlick event.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#remove-selected").click(function(){
    $(this).html("Sending...");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In fact I've tested that first, my problem is that it seems the form is submitted before the jQuery is executed. My request take some time and I want the button to change while the html request is executed.

Comment: Works in Chrome and Firefox but not with Safari. Any idea?

Comment: Alrick, since Apple has stopped to release it for Windows, I can't test it but you can do it yourself by going step by step. First, find the problem, is it click event or html method ? Use console.log for example. Then, try an alternative when you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You code is correct, you may have forgotten to embed it inside a `$(document).ready()` method.

Comment: Thanks Sébastien but I've embed my code inside a `$(document).ready()`